# python for loops and dictionary values

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I am learning python and trying to make a phone book. Fairly standard exercise, but I am having issues trying to get my search function go through each value in the dictionary. It will only return the first item if there is a match, otherwise it just returns `None` and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Using python 2.6 for no particular reason.

```
phonebook = {"id": 1, "fname" : "Mario", "lname": "Mario", "phone": "XXX-XXX-XXXX"}, \
        {"id": 2, "fname" : "Luigi", "lname": "Mario", "phone": "505-123-4567"}

def search_fname(name):
    name = str.capitalize(name)
    for n in phonebook:
        if name == n["fname"]:
            return n["id"]
        else:
            print "No match found."
            return 0

def search():
    name = raw_input("Please enter the first name: ")
    pid = search_fname(name)
    if pid != 0:
        for n in phonebook:
            if n["id"] == pid:
                print n["fname"], n["lname"], n["phone"]
```

Answer (score 5):

You return *on your first test*:

```
for n in phonebook:
    if name == n["fname"]:
        return n["id"]
    else:
        print "No match found."
        return 0
```

So if the first entry in your phonebook, bound to `n`, is a match (so `name = "Mario"`), you return `n['id']`, otherwise you return `0`. Your `for` loop never gets to iterate over the rest of the phonebook here as you exited the function already.

Remove the `else` block altogether; you won't know if there is no match until you have tried all entries, so put your `print` *after* the `for` loop:

```
for n in phonebook:
    if name == n["fname"]:
        return n["id"]

print "No match found."
return 0
```

Comment: I guess he also needs to print all the matches. Considering this line *search function go through each value in the dictionary*, So it means that he will have to store the values matched somewhere and return as a list. :/ Or have I misunderstood the question

Comment: @BhargavRao: The code returns the *first item in the phonebook if it matches*. They only need to return one match, but unless you enter `Mario` it'll never match anything else, because only the first entry is ever tested.

Comment: @BhargavRao: in other words, they are describing the symptoms, not the requirements.

Comment: Yep. Got it. But for a phonebook, it would be a better idea to have the code return all the matched strings, but in any case that is left for the OP to decide. Ty :)

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code to not return early, and it now catches and returns all matches if there are more than one.

```
def search_fname(name):
    name = str.capitalize(name)

    entries = []

    for n in phonebook:
        if name == n["fname"]:
           entries.append("{}, {}, {}"
                          .format(n["fname"], n["lname"], n["phone"])
                          )

    if len(entries) > 0:
        return entries

    return 0

def search():
    name = raw_input("Please enter the first name: ")
    pids = search_fname(name)
    if pids != 0:
        for pid in pids:
            print(pid)

search()
```

Comment: Why not just return the empty list? `if not pids:` would work for either an empty list and `0`, but an empty list communicates that there were no matches just as much but is consistent.

Comment: And the responsibility of formatting should really be in the function that prints, so I'd just use `entries.append(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get multiple results, you should not return anything before getting to the end of the loop. "return" breaks the loop, so no other result will be found after the first one (if any).

If you want to be able to return more than one, you should add the results to a list, which will be empty if nothing is found, and contain all the results if there are any. This code lists the entries found for the given name. Note that I didn't return the id only, but the full object, so you don't have to go through the loop another time to get the data in search().

```
def search_fname(name):
    name = str.capitalize(name)
    found = []
    for n in phonebook:
        if name == n["fname"]:
            found.append(n)
    return found

def search():
    name = raw_input("Please enter the first name: ")
    entries = search_fname(name)
    for n in entries:
        print n["fname"], n["lname"], n["phone"]
```

Tested on python2.7. If you're learning, you might consider using an up-to-date version of python.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation made it click!